# Can you access the local file system in a MAUI Blazor hybrid app

Tags: blazor, maui, blazor-hybrid

Can you access the local file system in a MAUI Blazor hybrid app.  Particularly get folder contents and access a file in a folder outside of the MAUI app's folder - eg. c:\

The app would be MAUI acting as a simple placeholder for the Blazor WebView, and it's within the Blazor components I want to access the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, a Blazor Hybrid app is not bound to the browser sandbox. Anything you can do with a "regular" .NET MAUI app, you can do with a Blazor Hybrid app.

This is of course assuming that you have added the right permissions to the manifest files for each platform that you want to run on.

Comment: 1) Gerald, I'm not finding any example of accessing files from the Blazor part (Razor code in a Blazor component) of Maui Blazor. The closest I've found is [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid static files / Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-maui), but that is about accessing MauiAsset files. Can you provide a link, or expand your answer here, so I can link to it as needed? 2) In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414412/read-file-placed-in-external-storage-from-js-in-maui-blazor), can js code access files?

Comment: It's not any different than accessing the filesystem from any other .NET project. `File.ReadAllText("C:\foo\bar\thing.txt");` should just work, assuming that you have the mobile app permissions in order. Also it's good to keep in mind that, especially on iOS, the file system isn't a thing you can just access like you would on Windows. But what I'm trying to say: Blazor is not a factor in this, if you know how to do it in Xamarin/.NET MAUI, that should work in Blazor in .NET MAUI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but so far there are some limitations over the `javascript/html` side. For example, you can't play video from file storage without using a file picker (HTML input element). The following code is not working (again so far until 2023-10-23).

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" src="C:/Mahdi/yourVideo.mp4" controls></video>
```